# LAG function and NULLS

Tags: sql, null, google-bigquery, lag

So I'm trying to use a LAG function (Google BigQuery) and my first value is a NULL.

[image]

I'm using a lag function to get lag_Value_1,lag_Value_2...
In here :

```
SELECT ITEM,row_A,row_B,date,Value_1,Value_2,Value_3,Value_4,Value_5,
         LAG(Value_1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_1,
         LAG(Value_2,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_2,
         LAG(Value_3,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_3,
         LAG(Value_4,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_4,
         LAG(Value_5,0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_5
FROM table
```

Any help to fill out lag_Value_1,2,3,4,5....for ITEM 2?

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: so I'm getting ALL NULLS for lag_value_1...for ITEM 2...I actually expect lag_value_1 to be null....and lag_value_2 to be F ,lag_value_3 to be G , lag_value_4 to be H...

Comment: what is expected result/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel below is what you are looking for:

```
  LAST_VALUE(Value_1 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A ASC) AS lag_Value_1,
  LAST_VALUE(Value_2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A ASC) AS lag_Value_2,
  LAST_VALUE(Value_3 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A ASC) AS lag_Value_3,
  LAST_VALUE(Value_4 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A ASC) AS lag_Value_4,
  LAST_VALUE(Value_5 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A ASC) AS lag_Value_5
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the three argument form of lag?

```
SELECT ITEM, row_A, row_B, date, Value_1, Value_2, Value_3, Value_4, Value_5,
       LAG(Value_1, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_1,
       LAG(Value_2, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_2,
       LAG(Value_3, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_3,
       LAG(Value_4, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_4,
       LAG(Value_5, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY row_A asc) as lag_Value_5
FROM table
```

The three arguments are:

- The value to lag.
- The number of rows to go back.
- The default value.

Comment: I'm getting ALL NULLS for lag_value_1...for ITEM 2...I actually expect lag_value_1 to be null....and lag_value_2 to be F ,lag_value_3 to be G , lag_value_4 to be H